What is wrong with SQL syntax of my query?
I have such query in my program:
SELECT customer.Id, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, SUM(PeriodHours) AS SUMPeriodHours, PeriodDay 
FROM (
      (SELECT CustomerId, 
              (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(taskinterval.EndDateUtc) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(taskinterval.StartDateUtc)) / 3600 AS PeriodHours, 
              date(taskinterval.StartDateUtc) as PeriodDay
       FROM taskinterval
       WHERE StartDateUtc > @STARTDATE and StartDateUtc<@ENDDATE
      ) AS tmptbl
 ) 
INNER JOIN customer on customer.Id = tmptbl.CustomerId
GROUP BY PeriodDay, customer.Id, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName

It does not work neither in code of my program, nor in SqlWorkbench when I substitute '@ENDDATE' and '@STARTDATE'
It works fine on MariaDB 10.3.32 but on MySQL 8.0.35 it does not work, such error is shown:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') Inner Join customer on customer.Id = tmptbl.CustomerId                   group'

This error seems vague for me. I have looked at this article: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-10-4-and-mysql-8-/ but did not find anything that may help me with that question. How do I fix this query to make it compatible with MySQL ?

What is wrong with SQL syntax of my query? Excess parentesis which wraps the subquery (the closing parenthesis which starts the code fragment in the error message and matching opening parenthesis). In MySQL this means "convert the subquery output to scalar value". Remove them.

Why has this been closed? Isn't it important for future readers to know that MySQL has a an issue with additional parentheses that other DBMS only consider superfluous? I have voted to have this re-opened.

If MySQL has any problem with these parentheses, is this really related to programming?

@Nico Haase: Yes, it is. The various DBMS have different SQL dialects. Some allow grouping by alias names, others not. So, if someone tries to group by an alias name and their DBMS throws an error, they will find the answer on stackoverflow that some DBMS support the syntax, but theirs not. Same here. Usually, DBMS are fine with additional parentheses, but MySQL is special here. If a programmer stumbles upon this error, they will be happy to find an explanation on stackoverflow, because I am pretty sure this is hard to find in MySQL docs, if at all.

The tmptbl alias is in wrong position. Should be after the derived table. (I.e. after the final closing right parenthesis.) According to the ISO/ANSI SQL standard!

The immediate cause is an extra ( .. ):
FROM (( SELECT ... FROM taskinterval))

it should be
FROM ( SELECT ... FROM taskinterval)

To avoid such pesky errors, please keep your query simple, split it into easy to read fragments, in your case CTE:
WITH tmptbl AS (
  SELECT CustomerId, 
         (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(taskinterval.EndDateUtc) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(taskinterval.StartDateUtc)) / 3600 AS PeriodHours, 
         date(taskinterval.StartDateUtc) AS PeriodDay
    FROM taskinterval
   WHERE StartDateUtc > @STARTDATE AND StartDateUtc < @ENDDATE 
)

  SELECT customer.Id, 
         customer.FirstName, 
         customer.LastName, 
         SUM(PeriodHours) AS SUMPeriodHours, 
         PeriodDay 
    FROM tmptbl
    JOIN customer ON customer.Id = tmptbl.CustomerId
GROUP BY customer.Id, 
         customer.FirstName, 
         customer.LastName,
         PeriodDay 


That code is being used in C# program. Doubt you can pack TWO queries in MySqlCommand call . It looks neat though

@Ivan P.: please, note, that it is one query (which can be executed as usual). Close analogy: we can have one program with several methods (not one huge Main)

@IvanP. It is allowed, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html the AllowBatch option

An extra ( ... ) is allowed, as long as it doesn't use a table alias. This is used for grouping set operations such as UNION and INTERSECT. https://dbfiddle.uk/a5Esl2So

Yeah, I see that FROM (( SELECT ... )) AS tmptbl ) does work on MySQL 8.9.36

It seems you have an extra set of parenthesis. Try this
    Select
    customer.Id,
    customer.FirstName,
    customer.LastName,
    SUM(PeriodHours) as SUMPeriodHours,
    PeriodDay
    from
    (
    SELECT
      CustomerId,
      (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(taskinterval.EndDateUtc) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(taskinterval.StartDateUtc)
      ) / 3600 as PeriodHours,
      date(taskinterval.StartDateUtc) as PeriodDay
    FROM
      taskinterval
    where
      StartDateUtc > @STARTDATE
      and StartDateUtc < @ENDDATE
    ) as tmptbl
     Inner Join customer on customer.Id = tmptbl.CustomerId
    group by
  PeriodDay,
  customer.Id,
  customer.FirstName,
  customer.LastName

